# Why does this imply invertibility?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In a paper I am reading, it says that, for matrices $U\in R^{n\times m}$ and $O\in R^{n\times m}$ with column rank $m$ for both, $range(U)=range(O)$ implies $U^T O$ is invertible. I don't see why this is true.

Thoughts?

Comment: Then let’s delete our comments, shall we?

Comment: Since they both have the same column/row rank, $m$, it can be seen as a matter of showing that $U^T O$ has rank $m$ which would imply it is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank of $U$ is $m$, and so is the rank of $U^TU$; this is an $m\times m$ matrix, so rank $m$ means that it is invertible. In particular, $U^T$ is a bijection from $\text{ran}(U)$ onto $\mathbb R^m$. As $O$ is one-to-one (because its column rank equals the size of its domain), $U^TO$ is one-to-one. Thus onto, and thus bijective.